# this error while running selenium script with Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium

I recently upgraded to 16.04.

I installed selenium==3.0.2 and now when I run the script, this is what I see:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aux.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 408, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 440, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1227, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 386, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 356, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
```

and this is all in the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('google.com')
```

Comment: your error doesn't include the actual error, just the traceback .  You missed the first few lines.

Comment: that's all raised in the terminal

Comment: you're right, my mistake.  For some reason I expeted otherwise.